# Limit MySQL Batch size in jConnector

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have a JDBC application, to convert insert statements into batch I used `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` in MySQL connection string but I also need to limit my batch size to 100. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server side `max_allowed_packet` will limit the count of `INSERT` clobbed together by `rewriteBatchedStatements`. As per [5.1.8 Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet):

> The maximum size of one packet or any generated/intermediate string, or any parameter sent by the mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function. The default is 64MB.

If you need more fine grained control you must use JDBC e.g. by calling `executeBatch()` after each N rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can make commit of current transaction (or flush session) every 100 rows you trying to insert.